# It is about Notepad++ regular expression replacement

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace

```
<th scope="col">@translate(Product)</th>
```

code row to

```
<th scope="col">{{trans("file.Product")}}</th>
```

in NotePad++ but I can't write exactly correct regular expression.
Help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<th scope="col">\K@translate\((.+?)\)(?=</th>)`
- Replace with: `{{trans("file.$1")}}`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<th scope="col">        # literally
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
@translate              # literally
\(                      # openning parenthesis
(.+?)                   # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\)                      # closing parenthesis
(?=</th>)               # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing tag after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I made a little change on your guidance that solved my problem find what: \K@translate\((.+?)\)  and replace with: {{trans\("file.$1"\)}}. It will help me replacing about 5000 occurrences.

Comment: @Delgerbayar: If you don't care of the tag, no needs to keep the `\K` in the regex, use simply: `@translate\((.+?)\)`